# Mapping an array with only certain props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

first time poster. I'm currently learning React-Native with MobX and I was wondering, after clicking a button to show the available products, what is the best way to map out the array with only certain props. For instance, you have 2 tabs, one for food and one for drinks, if I click on the button drinks,  I want to map out only items which have the value "beverage" thus ignoring the other two, in this case I will only get fanta and cola. Thanks in advance.

```
class ProductsStore {
  @observable products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'sandwich',
        description: 'tasty',
        price: 150,
        catergory: "food"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'fanta',
        description: 'orange drink',
        price: 250,
        catergory: "beverage"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'hamburger',
        description: 'meat',
        price: 350,
        catergory: "food"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'cola',
        description: 'caramel drink',
        price: 250,
        catergory: "beverage"
    }
];
}

export default ProductsStore;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will look something like this

```
products.filter(object => object.category === "beverage").map(rec => {
  return <div>{rec}</div>
})
```

You first filter array and then create a list of food or beverage